# Custom DOM properties not visible from an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple page with a single element, with `id="test"`. I made a simple extension with the following content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("test");
  console.log(test.value);
  test.value = 3;
});
```

Now, if I click the extension button, it prints `undefined`, and then keeps printing 3. However, if I try to access this value from the console, it is still undefined, and changing it does not affect what the extension prints. Is there any way to actually access this value from an extension?

**Update:** okay I found out that extensions run in a separate environment that does not share 'expandos' with the main script, so I need to inject a script into the actual page to do that.

Comment: You mean console.log(elem.value)? Extensions are definitely able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`Content scripts` execute in a special environment called an **isolated** world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page. It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse: JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any variables defined by `content scripts`.

Although the execution environments of `content scripts` and the pages that host them are isolated from each other, they share access to the page's DOM. If the page wishes to communicate with the content script (or with the extension via the content script), it must do so through the shared DOM.

1. **Using window.postMessage**

In content script -

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();

    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
      // We only accept messages from ourselves
      if (event.source != window)
        return;

      if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
        console.log("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
        port.postMessage(event.data.text);
      }
    }, false);
```

In your page script -

```
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",
    function() {
  window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
}, false);
```

2. **Injecting script in your page:**

In content script -

```
  function main() {
      var elem = document.getElementById("test");
      console.log(test.value);
      test.value = 3;
  }
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('('+ main +')();'));
 (document.body || document.head).appendChild(script);
```

3. **Creating Custom Events**:

In either the injected or your content script add an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('yourCustomEvent', function (e)
{
  var data=e.detail;
  console.log("received "+data);
});
```

On the other side (content or injected script) call the event:

```
var data="anything";
var evt=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
evt.initCustomEvent("yourCustomEvent", true, true, data);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: half of this is copied from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score 0):

One thing that elements definitely share between page and extension context are `data-*` attributes.

You can manipulate them through the `.dataset` interface:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("test");
  console.log(test.dataset.value);
  test.dataset.value = 3; // will become "3"
});
```

This will correspond to `data-value="3"` attribute on the element in the DOM.

More generally,

```
function storeValue(id, key, value) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if(!element) throw Error("Element #" + id = " not found");
  element.dataset[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
}

function readValue(id, key) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if(!element) throw Error("Element #" + id = " not found");
  var value = element.dataset[key];
  if(typeof value == "undefined") return undefined;
  else return JSON.parse(value);
}

storeValue("test", "value", 3);
console.log(readValue("test", "value"));
```

I added the serialization/deserialization, since attributes can only be strings.